# SHELL printing just right part after . (DOT)

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I need to find just extension of all files in directory (if there are 2 same extensions, its just one). I already have it. But the output of my script is like

```
test.txt
test2.txt
hello.iso
bay.fds
hellllu.pdf
```

Im using grep -e -e '.' and it just highlight DOTs
And i need just these extensions give in one variable like txt,iso,fds,pdf

Is there anyone who could help? I already had it one time but i had it on array. Today I found out It's has to work on dash too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` with `awk` to get all unique extensions:

```
find . -type f -name '?*.?*' -print0 | 
awk -F. -v RS='\0' '!seen[$NF]++{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Hello. This code works. But there is one exception. When i have files in dir (and subdirs) for example text.txt some.iso hw.pdf .hellou  (where hellou is hidden file), how can I "take that exception off the list?" So exteptions will be just .txt, .iso and .pdf?

Answer (score 0):

can be done with `find` as well, but I think this is easier

```
for f in *.*; do echo "${f##*.}"; done | sort -u
```

if you want to assign a comma separated list of the unique extensions, you can follow this

```
ext=$(for f in *.*; do echo "${f##*.}"; done | sort -u | paste -sd,)

echo $ext

csv,pdf,txt
```

alternatively with `ls`

```
ls -1 *.* | rev | cut -d. -f1 | rev | sort -u | paste -sd,
```

rev/rev is required if you have more than one dot in the filename, assuming the extension is after the last dot.  For any other directory simply change the part `*.*` to `dirpath/*.*` in all scripts.

I'm not sure I understand your comment.  If you don't assign to a variable, by default it will print to the output.  If you want to pass directory name as a variable to a script, put the code into a script file and replace dirpath with $1, assuming that will be your first argument to the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# print unique extension in the directory passed as an argument, i.e.

ls -1 "$1"/*.* ...
```

if you have sub directories with extensions above scripts include them as well, to limit only to file types replace `ls ..` with

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" | ...
```

Comment: Well thats work but only in current dir :/ If i have in variable for example files saved that output (in the code link in upper post) how cna i assemble it with that for cycle? (It's all in one function. I call it in "main" like printf "Extensions: %s" "output of function"

Comment: `ls -1` is useless here, as `printf '%s\n' *.*` will do the job as well. This will break with filenames containing newlines, though.

Comment: Just one more thing. When i call dir for example something.dirsomething, script will take .dirsomething like a file extension. What can I do with that? Thank for response